# Deactivate Login Screen for certain pages in ngx-rocket angular 7 starter kit

Tags: angular, angular7, canactivate

I'm using the ngx-rocket angular7 starter kit. It has a guard implemented that will make the login screen pop up if i'm not logged in yet. to implement a registration page I don't want the login screen to pop up though, the registration page should be public. does anyone know how to deactivate the login screen there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on how you implement your registration page, show your code, where you define the link and route for registration. Normally, that template uses `AuthenticationGuard` in helper function. Check `About` module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  Shell.childRoutes([
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent, data: { title: extract('About') } }
  ])
];
```

If you define your registration module with routes without `Shell.childRoutes` helper, it will not trigger `AuthenticationGuard` and thus won't redirect to `login`. Like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, data: { title: extract('Register') } }
];
```

If one also wants to preserve original `Shell` functionality, routes can be as following:

```
const routes: Routes = [
   {
      path: '',
      component: ShellComponent,
      children: [
        { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, data: { title: extract('Register') } }
      ],
      // canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
      // Reuse ShellComponent instance when navigating between child views
      data: { reuse: true }
    }

];
```

As an alternative, helper can be defined in `Shell` it self:

```
export class Shell {

  // existing helper
  static childRoutes(routes: Routes): Route {
    return {
      path: '',
      component: ShellComponent,
      children: routes,
      canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
      // Reuse ShellComponent instance when navigating between child views
      data: { reuse: true }
    };
  }

  // add new helper without guard
  static unAuthenticatedChildRoutes(routes: Routes): Route {
    return {
      path: '',
      component: ShellComponent,
      children: routes,
      // Reuse ShellComponent instance when navigating between child views
      data: { reuse: true }
    };
  }
}
```

And then, in your component:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  Shell.unAuthenticatedChildRoutes([
    { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, data: { title: extract('Register') } }
  ])
];
```

Comment: Just remember, of other parameters that are used in default `childRoutes`. I added another example.